# Excel: use cell IF condition is true, ELSE iterate formula to next row AND use the same cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

It's much easier to give an example of what I'm trying to accomplish...

I have this data with three columns:  a unique ID, a player name, and a team name:

[image: source_data]

This data is the source for the data that I'm trying to create, which has two columns:

1. the UID of any player from *Source_Data* who's on The Champs, and
2. the name of any player from *Source_Data* who's on The Champs

Therefore, the data I want should look like this:

[image: Desired output for table]

To get this data I need to go through each row in the Source_Data and -- if the player is a member of The Champs -- get their UID/Name and put it into the table (note that the actual spreadsheet I'm creating is far more complicated and this is the method that I'll have to use -- that is, going through each row and seeing if the player is a member of "The Champs").

This sounds easy, except there's no way to **not put anything** if the player is ***not*** a member of The Champs.  What I mean is that this is table I *actually* get:

[image: the actual table that is created]

Here are the formulas that I use to get this data:

[image: formulas]

How can I accomplish this?  How can I create the desired table?  That is, how can I *not* add something to the cell if the player on row[i] isn't a member of The Champs?  How can I *only* populate the cell if the player on row[i] *is* a member of The Champs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Filter` function.

Put this in Top Left Cell of your destination

```
=FILTER($A:$B,$C:$C="The Champs")
```

No need to copy down, it will "Spill"

[image]

Comment: Grazi!!!!!  This is what I've been looking for!!  This is one of those probably super-common super-obvious things-that-people-use-all-the-time, but unless-you-know-about-it-you-can't-find-it kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have Office 365, then highlight row 2, go to Data ribbon and click Filter.  Then go to Team cell, C2, and click there.  A dropdown will let you pick Champs, after which you will only see rows with Champs in column C.

Comment: That is manual tasks. If it is one time activity then it is good option. Otherwise there are some other formula to filter data for non 365 excel.